# Recovering root access on MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Alright, `root@localhost` was not connectable with PHP, so I deleted it and created a new root account.

All was fine until I was about to grant privileges when I realized, that none of the other accounts had grant privileges.

How to get access back to root privileges on the DB?

Comment: please help, And yes I have tried --init-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See for example this answer: https://superuser.com/a/603027

```
Start the MySQL server instance or daemon with the --skip-grant-tables option (security setting).

$ mysqld --skip-grant-tables

Execute these statements.

$ mysql -u root mysql
$mysql> UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('my_password') where USER='root';
$mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

So just do the necessary GRANT statements in the second part.
Like explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1709138/6368697

```
If the GRANT ALL doesn't work, try:

Stop mysqld and restart it with the --skip-grant-tables option.
Connect to the mysqld server with just: mysql (i.e. no -p option, and username may not be required).

Issue the following commands in the mysql client:

UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y' WHERE User='root';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

After that, you should be able to run GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost'; and have it work.
```